# Augmentation Ideal of Universal Enveloping Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am confused with the statement that "consider the augmentation map   $\epsilon_L :\mathfrak{U}(L) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ which is the unique algebra homomorphism induced by $\epsilon_{L}(x)=0 , \forall x \in L$   (I hope $L$ here is seen as the copy $T^1$  in $\mathfrak{U}(L)$)  where  $\mathfrak{U}(L)$ is the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra $L$ and the kernel of $\epsilon_{L}$ is said to be the augmentation ideal. My confusion is that if $\epsilon_{L}(x)=0 , \forall x \in L$  then does not that imply $ker(\epsilon_{L})$ is just $\mathfrak{U}(L)/\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: $\ker \epsilon_L=\bigoplus_{n\geq 1}T^n(L)$.

Comment: It should NOT be $T^n(L)$ assuming $T^i(L)s $ are the tensor powers of $L$.Rather it might be $\ker \epsilon_L=\bigoplus_{n\geq 1} \mathfrak{U}_{n}(L)$  where $\{ \mathfrak{U}_{i}(L) \}$ is the obvious grading. Actually I did not like the description of the ideal in terms of $kernel$ of the map. One can just say The ideal $ \bigoplus_{n\geq 1} \mathfrak{U}_{n}(L)$ is the augmentation ideal. It is an ideal is obvious.

Comment: You are right. That was a silly error (apparently I have a hang-over from answering a question on the relationship between the tensor algebra and the enveloping algebra). The point is that the kernel is **not** the quotient.

Comment: The augmentation map makes sense without knowing that the Lie algebra _injects_ to the enveloping algebra, is one little point. And then its kernel is undeniably an ideal. That kernel is a sub-object of the enveloping algebra, not a quotient. Similarly, it is not clear a-priori (before Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt) that the sum of the images of $\bigotimes^n \mathfrak g$ is direct, etc. But that info is not needed to describe the augmentation ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to write this $\mathfrak U(L)\backslash\mathbb F$, right? Since it does not make sense to write $\mathfrak U(L)/\mathbb F$, because $\mathbb F$ not is an ideal of $\mathfrak U(L)$. The correct is $\ker \epsilon_L=\mathfrak U(L)\backslash\mathbb F^*$, this is direct by definition of $\epsilon_L$. Moreover, you can show that $\mathfrak U(L)=\mathbb F\oplus\ker\epsilon_L$ if you consider $\mathbb F$ is the subalgbera of $\mathfrak U(L)$ generated by $1.$